# Yo Command not found After install npm

Tags: npm

[Link](http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html) Using this tutorial install the npm ,Installing npm its working,But after install npm am checking version of the yo,

Using that yo command to check version its showing error yo command not found like that.How to solve this?

```
$ npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli

yo --version && bower --version && grunt --version
```

Comment: I'd guess you have to check your path, but a properly installed npm should create a correct link... Are the other commands (e.g. bower) accessbile?

Comment: Yes npm installed properly,How Should create correct link?